# Make USB storage device on-demand-read-only

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive, usb-storage, read-only

Context : I store some sensitive documents on USB drive, and want to protect the data, also it is extremely important that the drive is accessible on all operating systems (linux/mac/windows).

End Goal: Prevent accidental overwrite/format/data-deletion on the USB drive

How can this be done?

If I understand correctly, the only possible way is to block the write command in the USB firmware using "BadUSB" hack tools, but that is only works on certain chipsets (i.e, Phison 2251-03).

Is there any other way to make the USB pen drive write protected? Or is there any existing resource that explains the process on writing the firmware to block the write command (also to burn the same on the device).

Note: I know I should keep backup, and I do, but I would still like the drive to be as tamper-proof as possible.

Answer (score 1):

The most simple way is to get an USB stick which has write-protect switch. That way you can protect it at any time. This exists since the old USB sticks era.

This is also the only cross-OS-compatible way to do so.

Firmware modifications work partially and are risky because they can have unforeseen consequences.

Other tricks are OS-dependent.

Comment: Do you know of any resource where i can start to hack on the firmware of my USB drive to make it read only?

Comment: The tools used in the official BadUSB demo were released and are available here: https://github.com/brandonlw/Psychson .There is no universal editor at this point because there are too many manufacturers and each one as a different type of fmw.

Comment: Yea, I already found that one....